# Parsing JSON on Windows Phone 7

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I'm trying to do some simple JSON manipulation on the Windows Phone 7. JSON.NET looks great, but VS2010 complains when I try to add a reference to it.

It let me add the Silverlight dll, but warned me that it could result in weird app behavior, so I'm skeptical that it would actually work.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) looks like a fine way to serialize and deserialize data, but I need to actually query it. Could I just use this technique to serialize it to a `IQueryable`, then use LINQ on it? Can I somehow convert the JSON to XML and use LINQ?

Or should I do hacky and sad string manipulation myself?

**Update**: For some reason, I can't even get VS2010 to recognize `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

```
        // works
        DataContractSerializer ser1 = new DataContractSerializer();

        // the type or namespace 'DataContractJsonSerializer' could not be found ...
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer();
```

**Update 2**: The following also complains:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
```

The error:

> The type or namespace name 'Json' does
>   not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)

Am I doing something wrong, or is JSON not supported in wp7?

**Update 3**: Looks like `DataContractJsonSerializer` is in the System.Servicemodel.Web namespace.

**Update 4**: I added a reference to the Silverlight JSON.NET dll, and it appears to be working fine for now. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Just curious; how is developing for WP7?

Comment: Why do you still use JSON.Net when you found DataContractJsonSerializer in System.ServiceModel.Web ? Any Pros?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as per your Update 3 (almost):
`DataContractJsonSerializer` is in the `System.Servicemodel.Web.dll` assembly, but in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` namespace.

It's caught quite a few people out.

Glad you seem to have got this working.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you use the DataContract attribute, this is in the  `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace and in `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` assembly.