# Json Serialization for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, deserialization

I was trying to implement parsing a JSON response as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c/1218902#1218902) for my Windows Phone 7 project in C#. But I am stuck with a compilation error as "The type or namespace name 'Serializable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have the imports using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json; I am not sure what are import I am missing. I tried to include using System.ServiceModel.Web; But the Web part is not recognized.

I thought my project is not pointing to the right framework from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found). But in the Assembly information, there is no option for me to change the target framework.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999117/parsing-json-on-windows-phone-7) looks like a similar problem to mine, but I couldn't find the JSON.NET in .net dlls which is filtered for Windows Phone.

Can someone help me to get this JSON thing working for Windows Phone 7.

Thank in Advance.

**EDIT - 7/3/11**

My Jason response is 
{ "serviceresponse" : { "servicename" : "RequestRegisterUser", .....

And my Response objects are:

```
[DataContract]
       public class serviceresponse
       {
             [DataMember]
           public String servicename { get; set; }
           .
           .
           .
```

And my Deserialize method:

```
 public static T Deserialise<T>(string json)
   {
       T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
       using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
       {
           DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
           obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
           return obj;
       }
   }
```

Now I am getting this error after Deserializing the response:
servicename Could not evaluate expression   string

( I could not import System.ServiceModel.Web though I have the dll in the reference. A compilation error on the .Web part (The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel') )

**EDIT** After more research, I found my response when viewed in the debugger is actually 
{
    \"serviceresponse\": {
        \"servicename\": \"RequestRegisterUser\",.....
I searched for this and found this could be a problem. How can I format it to correct JSON String??

Comment: Could you post the code that's not compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Though my class name is "serviceresponse", I used another wrapper class as

```
public class Response
{
   public serviceresponse serviceres;//Don't Do this....
}
```

where I used the variable name for serviceresponse as serviceres. But when I changed it to " serviceresponse" its all working.

```
public class Response
{
   public serviceresponse serviceresponse;//This fixed it.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference to both  System.Runtime.Serialization and System.ServiceModel.Web assemblies. The `DataContractJsonSerializer` is defined in System.ServiceModel.Web assembly in the Silverlight version of the framework, that's why you need the extra assembly reference.

And by the way JSON.NET is a a popular open-source JSON framework for .Net and you could find more about it [here](http://json.codeplex.com/). It's not part of the .Net framework, that's why you can't find it.

**Edit:**

1. About the compilation, in Silverlight the `DataContractJsonSerializer` is in the   `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` namespace, but in the assembly System.ServiceModel.Web (in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll), which is a bit confusing. So you use it like this - `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer`, but need the extra assembly reference. You also need to reference the System.Runtime.Serialization assembly as well, because that is where the `DataContract` attribute is defined. I see you have already successfully compiled the code, but I hope the extra explanation makes it more clear for future readers.
2. About the serialization itself - as you have already found out, you will need two objects, simply because that's the structure of the json. However, the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes have a `Name` property that you can use instead of changing the name of the fields. Also, you can use properties instead of fields if you like.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "servicename")]
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class Response
{
    [DataMember(Name = "serviceresponse")]
    public ServiceResponse ServiceResponse { get; set; }
}
```

And one last thing - you don't need the call to  Activator.CreateInstance(); in your `Deserialise` method.

Comment: Thank you. That explains about Json.net. I have posted my source code. I could not import System.ServiceModel.Web though I have the dll in the reference. A compilation error on the .Web part (The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel')

Answer (score 1):

It certainly would help if you posted your code. So I can only guess:

I assume you have something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

But that's a mix-up of two serialization concepts, one of which is not supported in Phone 7. The correct attributes are *DataContract* and *DataMember*:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have added my source code, which is similar to your response. Can you take another shot at it now?