# Do I need to serialize an object for storing it or without serialization it can be stored in C#.Net using WP 7.1 SDK?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to store custom objects in `isolatedstoragesettings` of **WP7.1** application. My program works well if I hard-code it. But without hard-coding it gives exception on Save() method of `isolatedstoragesettings`  class.

Exception is:

> Type 'PhoneApp4.Classes.Objects.Person' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.

Please Provide some sample code or suggestion to begin, because I am new to windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should make it serializable. Check out this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268151/XML-Serialization-in-Windows-Phone-7-Tips-and-Tric

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Please can you also give me link for JSON Serializer.

Comment: I would recommend http://json.codeplex.com/ Here is a related post on OS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561646/json-serialization-for-windows-phone-7